# GET data from server via JQuery call and load into DIV without refreshing page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've spent the best part of 90 minutes sifting through the many tutorials relating to this problem.

Instead of using the rather long winded way of creating a XHR object , sending the request, getting the data back, doing a getElementById to find the div then loading the response into the div. I'm looking for a far more simpler - easier on the eye way of doing it and so have found myself looking at JQuery.

However none of the tuts seem to do what i want unless i'm overlooking something. I just want to pass in a url, perform the request - data is passed back as html, then i want to inject it into a specific div.

Can someone please show me a simple solution to this problem, or link me to a straightforward tutorial if one is known?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#divID').load('yourURL');
```

*edit* just noticed that you want to "inject" it.  The previous line will replace the contents of the div.  If you want to append it, you'd do the following:

```
$.get('yourURL', function(data) {
    $('#divID').append(data);
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/, http://api.jquery.com/load/, http://api.jquery.com/get/, http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: okay the url is a request which performs a number of different server side things which output XML, an XSL stylesheet then transforms this to HTML so will this still work?

Comment: As long as the response from the GET request is HTML, it doesn't matter to jQuery as to how that HTML was generated.  It *could* give you issues if the MIME type header isn't set to "text/html", but I don't think it will.

Comment: i'll check it out, thanks for the response - straight to the point no messing around.

Answer (score 3):

check out:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/ajaxpagefetcher.shtml

he has posted cut and paste for ajax loading on both page load as well as when a link is clicked.

For my purposes, instead of having the URL in the HREF, I involked the ajax load from the onClick option of the anchor tag, but had to remove javascript: from javascript:ajaxpagefetcher.load to get it to work in that configuration; this was due to the fact that the href URL of the anchor tag I wanted to be a totally different link than the ajax page. Ie, my hyper link was for a banner ad to the URL of said third party web site that when user clicked opens up in a new window, (target ="_blank"), breaking out of frames my site is running in so as to open the new third party web site with the proper URL including affiliate code information instead of being a frame on my site, but on a user clicking on said banner ad link, i wanted to involke a counter script to accumulate the total number of clicks for that particular banner ad.

This is all working for me to load a htm file into a DIV container which is hidden from the user, as far as the ajax load fetching of the counter script is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need, it loads the response of the url into the div.

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#example").load("http://mysite/ajaxpage");
</script>
```

jQuery "load" documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

You can also add a callback function...

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#example").load("http://mysite/ajaxpage", function () { alert("Done"); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/load/ should be as simple as:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```