# how to scrape a list of data from a url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I need to scrape a json data from this url:   https://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:NIFTY using jquery. once its scraped i need to pass those value from respected key to a real time updating html table. i am really very new to this.. so please anyone can helping me out to solve this issue.

I tried to solve the same problem with ajax also.i am very new to this front end work so please help me out for solve this issue.

Comment: Can you share your partial/attempted code? for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924748/get-data-from-server-via-jquery-call-and-load-into-div-without-refreshing-page

Comment: Please show us what you've did so far ...

Comment: what exactly you mean by scrape a list of data from url? This url is returning a response which is a json object. But not sure what you mean by _scrape_

Answer (score 0):

The url returns a `JSONP` object. You can use the `ajax` function of jQuery to receive the data as an javascript object and do further work with it ...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:NIFTY",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.length) {
            for (i = 0, l = response.length; i < l; i++) {
                // example, log property 't' of each entry to the console
                console.log(response[i].t);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/qLrhoutL/)**

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go through the data and generate the html for it.

You can use the `getJSON` function of jquery to fetch the data

```
$.getJSON('https://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:NIFTY&callback=?', function(data){
     console.log(data[0]);
 });
```

Since its a `jsonp` we need to add the `callback` param in the url